# Allow selection of Tables in DAX/Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, switch-statement, dax

The following code snippet below allows the selection of different measures, however, I wish to do the same but not selecting measures, rather selecting different tables. The problem is that both IF and SWITCH functions only can return a scalar value and not a table. Is there anyone that has a suggestion? Lastly, I've attached what I wished to work.

P.S The code snippets are copied from [THIS](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/comparative-analysis-by-different-values-in-same-dimension-in/ba-p/3283444) superb description on creating a comparative report in Power BI.

```
Switch Measures = {"Reseller Sales Amount","Reseller Sales Margin", "Reseller Sales PY", "Reseller Sales Margin PY","Reseller Sales Order Qty"}
```

```
Switch Value = IF (
    HASONEFILTER ( 'Switch Measures'[Value] ),
    SWITCH (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Switch Measures'[Value] ),
        "Reseller Sales Amount", [Reseller Sales Amount],
        "Reseller Sales Margin", [Reseller Sales Margin],
        "Reseller Sales PY", [Reseller Sales PY],
        "Reseller Sales Margin PY",[Reseller Sales Margin PY],
        "Reseller Sales Order Qty",[Reseller Sales Order Qty]
    )
)
```

```
FilteredTable_test = 
    FILTER(
        MyTable,
        SWITCH(
            SELECTEDVALUE('Switch Table filter'[Filter]),
            "Filter 1", MyTable[Filter 1] = CALCULATE(MAX(MyTable[Filter 1]), ALLEXCEPT(MyTable, MyTable[Category])),
            "Filter 2", MyTable[Filter 2] = CALCULATE(MAX(MyTable[Filter 2]), ALLEXCEPT(MyTable, MyTable[Category]))
        )
    )
```

Comment: Can you share the code that **you** would like to perform, **if** `IF/SWITCH` did support non-scalar value return.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've now added my DAX attempt to the initial question.

Comment: Your code above returns a table so I'm assuming this is for a Calculated Table? If so Calculated Tables and Calculated Columns are calculated at dataset refresh time, in saying these won't update with report interaction. Could you provide more detail to your scenario? There are ways arounds the IF/SWITCH scalar value restriction, but will need to understand what your are aiming to do.

Comment: I'll try to describe as good as possible. With one slicer ("Switch Table Filter") the user chooses which filter to apply to the main table. With my calculated table above, I wish to return different tables depending on which filter column is applied.  I suppose my initial problem phrasing was wrong. Since the FILTER function requires a boolean expression that is what I need to return from the SWITCH function.

Comment: Now we are getting closer. Since you want the visual to update depending on slicer selection, you will need to do this via a Measure, and add this Measure as filter to the visual. Will post an answer soon.

Comment: In order to clarify, I want the calculated table and not any specific visual to update depending on the slicer selection.

Comment: As mentioned above, Calculated Tables are calculated at dataset refresh time, and are not dynamic (ie able to interact with the report like slicers and selections). So while you can create a Calculated Table, it will be static and will **not** change/update with any slicers.

Comment: Oh yes, then your option with Measure as filter is viable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are wanting to filter a table based on Slicer selection to show the max value for either column A or B for each Category.

If so then try creating a Measure similar to:

```
Slicer Filter count = 
  var max1 = CALCULATE(MAX(MyTable[Filter 1]), ALLEXCEPT(MyTable, MyTable[Category]))
  var max2 = CALCULATE(MAX(MyTable[Filter 2]), ALLEXCEPT(MyTable, MyTable[Category]))
  
  return SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('Switch Table filter'[Filter]),
    "Filter 1",
      COUNTROWS( FILTER(MyTable, MyTable[Filter 1] = max1) ),
    "Filter 2",
      COUNTROWS( FILTER(MyTable, MyTable[Filter 2] = max2) )
  )
```

Then add this new Measure as Visual filter in the Filter pane and set it to `is not blank`.